# Store frequently used terminal commands in a file

Tags: command-line, bashrc

Okay, so I want add a command to my Desktop (Or any convenient location), and whenever I run it I want it to clone the HTML5 boilerplate.

```
$ git clone git://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate.git
```

And I'm tired of typing it out all the time. So how could I store my commands in a file?.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open your `~/.bashrc` and put this at the end:

```
alias boil='git clone git://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate.git'
```

or alternatively, this

```
boil() {
  git clone git://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate.git
}
```

From now on, in every new terminal you can use the command `boil` as an alternative to your long command.

The second version is to prefer, because is more flexible being able to accept and manage parameter, for example if you define

```
boil() {
  [[ -z "$1" ]] && set "github.com"
  git clone git://"$1"/paulirish/html5-boilerplate.git
}
```

you can easily change server, if there are mirror.

```
# without a parameter, the function will use a default
boil
# override the default providing explicitly a server parameter
boil othergit.com
```

It is only an example, your fantasy surely will think up something more useful.

Obviously you can add as many functions as you need.

Answer (score -3):

Why not create a document with that command, and every time you wish to use it you can simply copy and paste it into the terminal.

Comment: -1 Because this doesn't answer the question in the way that they are looking for.