# Problem using Virtual Terminal

Tags: virtual-terminal

How can I copy-paste following command:

```
rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal
gconftools --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal
```

into a virtual-terminal?

Comment: Why can't you use a terminal window in your desktop environment?

Comment: I cannot use the terminal normally,because after a command and my password the output of the terminal is" sudo: apt-get: command not found". I have tried to remove and re-install the terminal using synaptic package manager,but no change in the output. Hence I want to try the abovementioned method.

Comment: So you tried to reinstall `gnome-terminal` and something went wrong , right ? There's also `xterm`. Ubuntu comes with two GUI terminal emulators by default

Comment: And you can use Shift + Insert to paste copied stuff. But copy line by line, because if you try to put two commands together, it wont work. OR you can do. `rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal; gconftools --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal` As one line. See the semicolon ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use the standard terminal:

> ...I cannot use the terminal normally ...

start your installed packet manager Synaptic and install an other terminal `xterm`.

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `xterm` and <kbd>Return</kbd>

Now you can copy and paste:

- mark the command with the left mouse button
- paste the command with the middle mouse button

---

Alternatively write a short script and start the script in the virtual terminal:

- Start gedit and add the lines below:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal
  gconftools --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal
  ```
- Save the file as `foo` in your `home` folder and switch to tty.
- Login and make the script executable

  ```
  chmod +x ~/foo
  ```
- Start the script

  ```
  ./foo
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to access a desktop clipboard from a virtual terminal.

The easiest thing to do in this case is to save and run these commands as [a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223691/how-do-i-create-a-script-file-for-terminal-commands).