# Script for permissions

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts

Novice user here.

I have created an environment where there are three users, Tim, James and Harry.

I have created a group called Friends, which includes Tim and James. I have changed the permissions of this group using chmod 0770. Therefore the group has all capabilities (read, write, execute) and anyone outside the group has zero capabilities (i.e. Harry).

I want to automatically test that these permissions work using a script with the Harry user. I've tested it manually on one file called Homework.txt. To do this I entered: nano homework.txt, the permission was denied as expected.

If I want to create a script that carries out the same function but on different files (Photos.txt, Videos.txt, Album.txt) how would I go about doing this? Would be grateful if anyone can shed some light on this.

Thank you

Comment: Groups don't have any permissions, files have. To which files or folders did you grant 0770? To shed some light: get a list of files (folders are files too) and iterate over it in a loop. To test if you have access to the files you can `touch $file` it or `cat $file` it.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but I thought you could assign permissions to users, groups and others. Hence why I used the 0770 permission as 7 gives the group full capabilities (r ,w ,x) and 0 gives others (Harry, in my scenario) no capabilities. There is only one file that is involved at this point and this is the location.txt file @Kev Inski

Comment: Actually all files have specific permissions and groups use these permissions to get access to the files. But each file knows whom to give access or not.

Answer (score 2):

First, see: [How do I create a script file for terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/223691/760903) This covers creating the script itself.

To test whether you can write to a file, you can use:

```
[ -w filename ]
```

(And `-r` for reading, `-x` for executing.)

To do this for multiple files, you could use a `for` loop:

```sh
for f in Photos.txt Videos.txt Album.txt
do
    if [ -w "$f" ]
    then
        echo "Can write to $f."
    else
        echo "Can't write to $f."
    fi
    if [ -r "$f" ]
    then
        echo "Can read from $f."
    else
        echo "Can't read from $f."
    fi
done
```

`f` here is a variable that the shell will set to `Photos.txt`, `Videos.txt` and `Album.txt` in each iteration of the loop. `"$f"` is how you get the value of the variable.

Comment: Good answer, you may add some pitfalls like the `[ -w filename ]` statement needs the spaces otherwise it doesn't work and the error msg is not very helpful or that the variable `"$f"` in the test statement needs the quotes