# I want to locate a file anywhere in my system and unzip it. But I want to run a shell script for it

Tags: scripts, locate

I used locate command to locate the zip file as find was not working in this case.
Then run unzip it manually.
I am learning shell scripting.
How can I do it in shell script?

Comment: Edit a text file, shellscript file, to include the command lines that you used manually, one line after the other, save the file and make it executable. It is a good idea to put a 'shebang' as the first line in the file; to make it use bash: `#!/bin/bash`. Please try, and if you need help to make it work correctly, please edit your original question to show your shellscript file as`code`.

Comment: There are several good tutorials that you can find if you browse the internet. Use a suitable search string, for example **bash shellscript tutorial**

Comment: See [How do I create a script file for terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223691/how-do-i-create-a-script-file-for-terminal-commands)

Comment: Why is find not working in this case? This can perfectly be done with find in one go.

Comment: Find will only search in that directory. I am talking about anywhere in system.

Comment: `find / -name filename` will search 'everywhere' (for the file 'filename'). You may need elevated permissions (prefix with `sudo`) to be able to search where a regular user lacks access. But `locate` is often much faster than `find`.